# How to find address of global variable at runtime?

Tags: c

We know that address of structure variables and global variables is assigned at runtime.
I have to pass these addresses to one function. I have only name of variables which is stored in two dimensional array. How it possible to do it?

As an example: there is some file which having global & structure variables. I have collected all the variable names in an array from a `.map` file, but I want to exact the address of the variables.

Comment: If they are global variables why would you need their addresses?

Comment: The `&` operator does the trick

Comment: @Cygwinnian: hi i am stored  variables in a array .I want to damp this variable in a file. so i need exact address of variables at runtime . which is not possible by passing the contains oa array one by one.

Comment: EdHeal: it is providing address of array/buffer which contains all variables not exact address of variables at runtime

Comment: Given that you have strings containing the names of the variables, you have to use something like `dlsym()` to find their addresses.  However, you will also need to know about their types to be able to determine the size of the variables and how to handle them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I have a map file(which contains all variables names). I extract those variables and store in char array[50]. i want to pass these by function writefile(newfile,variable_name,sizeOf(variable_name)); .how to pass variable name which pass exact address at runtime

Comment: JKB: no idea about dlsym.

Comment: @A_Gupta - I think you should rephrase the question. If you are into reflection - this is bad in most cases (either software or otherwise) you should have pointed this out.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot take the name of a variable as a string and turn that into an address, that's called introspection and standard C does not have that facility.

What you *can* do is provide your own mapping, something like:

```
int glob_one, glob_two;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int  *addr;
} tMap;

tMap map[] = {
    {"glob_one", &glob_one },
    {"glob_two", &glob_two },
};

int *findVar (char *key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(map) / sizeof(map[0]); i++) {
        if (strcmp (map[i].name, key) == 0) {
            return map[i].addr;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
:
int *glob_to_use = findVar ("glob_two");
if (glob_to_use != NULL)
    *glob_to_use = 42;
```

If you're using a POSIX system, [`dlsym`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) can get information about the global namespace:

```
int glob_one;
:
int *glob_to_use = dlsym (RTLD_DEFAULT, "glob_one");
if (glob_to_use != NULL)
    *glob_to_use = 42;
```

For example, the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
int glob_one;
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *glob_to_use;
    printf ("Old value is %d\n", glob_one);
    glob_to_use = dlsym (RTLD_DEFAULT, "glob_one");
    if (glob_to_use != NULL)
        *glob_to_use = 42;
    else
        puts (dlerror());
    printf ("New value is %d\n", glob_one);
    return 0;
}
```

when compiled under Linux with:

```
gcc -rdynamic -o testprog testprog.c -ldl
```

will produce:

```
Old value is 0
New value is 42
```

---

If you're working with Windows instead of POSIX systems, the equivalent call is `GetProcAddress()`. The following is the equivalent program to the one above:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int glob_one = 13;
}
int main (void) {
    std::cout << "Old value is " << glob_one << '\n';

    HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandle (NULL);
    int *pGlobal = (int*) GetProcAddress (hMod, "glob_one");
    *pGlobal = 42;

    std::cout << "New value is " << glob_one << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Note the use of `extern "C"` and the `dllexport`, both of which are necessary here. The first stops the name mangling so you can use the real name for the symbol lookup. The second exports the variable so that `GetProcAddress()` can find it.

Like the Linux one above, the output shows that you can access the global via its textual name:

```
pax> gpatest
Old value is 13
New value is 42
```

Comment: hi, i have more than 100 variables, which are stored in char array.  it is possible to make any map as u give direct name but i dont want to give name manually............please if any possible way then tell me

Comment: @A_Gupta: Just use the `dlsym` method but with the elements in your character arrays.

Comment: @A_Gupta: yes, I noticed you mentioned that in a comment which is why I gave the Windows equivalents. See the update - you may also want to mention the platform up front next time :-)

Comment: @A_Gupta, see the update. I've tested that in VC++ 2010 Express and it works okay.

Comment: your code is working. But i am getting some problem to define in my code. problem is that i have a char buff[100], in this my variable is stored one by one in loop, i dont known its type. i try to void * ptr but this one is null every time.

Comment: @A_Gupta, if you can't figure out the type behind the symbol, the address is basically useless. I would suggest asking a different question asking if there's a way to discover the type from the map file, which appears to be where you're sourcing the names from. A new question is the right way to go since 1/ it's only related tangentially to this one; and 2/ you'll get a larger response than if you just asked it in a comment box.

Answer (score 1):

you can access the address of variable by it's name like

```
int globvar = 5;    // global

{
    int *pglob_myvar = (int *)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "globvar");
    printf("global: %d\n",*pglob_myvar);
}
```

Comment: i dont know name. it is stored in char array. then it is possible.

Comment: @A_Gupta you say that you have name in `char array`. so use it simple.

Comment: @A_Gupta  RTLD_NEXT is not defined by the posix standard so as per @paxdiablo suggested use `RTLD_DEFAULT` instead `RTLD_NEXT`